# How to populate list from api and pass data to new page when item is clicked?(react native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, fetch

I am very new to react native and am trying to populate a list with an image and a heading using a fetch() call from a web service . I need this list to populate as soon as the page is displayed. I am struggling to find the right method/event to put my logic in .

Also i have a separate page to see the detailed article. Is there a clean  way to pass on information to this page so i can avoid making another api call or a  messy global variable.

Comment: Follow this tutorial ~> https://www.appcoda.com/react-native-introduction/ It goes through creating a movie app which makes use of the listview & fetch method.

Comment: Add the ListView with image and title in the render method of the App.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). It might seem a bit hard to understand while reading but the implementation is pretty simple and straight forward.

Also, take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.i894mh98e) article by Dan Abramov, the main contributor of Redux, talking about Presentational and Container components.